# passing tag field to other view wf7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, view

ok I need to pass the tag in this code to the next page but I dont know how to access it. Can someone help with this.

code :

```
 <ListBox x:Name="AgendaList" Width="450" Height="520" Margin="10" SelectionChanged="event_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image  Width="100" Stretch="Uniform" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="/SuperAgenda;component/Images/calendar.jpg" />
                            <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Title_}" Tag="{Binding EventId_}" />

                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I am using a button to send it over so I need to know how I can get at the tag data and have the button send it to the next page. 
my button looks like this but it sends no data:

```
private void viewEvent_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {



        string uri = String.Format("/Views/Event_View/Event_View.xaml?id={0}", clickedLink.Tag);
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));

    }
```

Any help would be nice thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, to *transfer data* between pages you should use  PhoneApplicationService class.

```
 PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["field"] = someField;
```

at your button tap/click event.

Then, on your next page get that value using cast

```
someField = (fieldType)PhoneApplicationService.Current.State["field"];
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: well kind of. I need to get the value of the tag sent to the next page. basiclly I need to know what event id the selected and send it to the next page to display that event.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the [Navigation Context](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page.navigationcontext%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) property of the page you navigated to.

```
if (this.NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("ProductId"))
{
    productID = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["ProductId"];
}
else
{
    productID = App.Current.Resources["FeaturedProductID"].ToString();
}
```

Comment: thanks for the idea but I dont think its what i need. I just need to get the value of the tag sent to the next page. I have examined this code from the link and it does not seem to fit what I need.

Comment: To get your tag value you simply do:

string tag = (string)this.NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];

Comment: the problem is I cannot get the value of the tag to send it over. where it is at is inaccessible. It would be nice if I could just give the textblock a name and then use name.tag to get the value.

Comment: I think now I get what your problem is. You can do so. In you XAML just do: `<TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding Title_}" Tag="{Binding EventId_}" />` in the code behind you can than do the following: `string uri = String.Format("/Views/Event_View/Event_View.xaml?id={0}", this.myTextBlock.Tag);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `Tag` property here is superfluous, as the `DataTemplate` in a bound control contains all the properties of your object. Use the `DataContext` to retrieve the object. Add a `Tap` event to the `StackPanel` in your `DataTemplate` (so the user can tap either the image or text):

```
private void StackPanel_Tap( object sender, GestureEventArgs e ) {
    int eventid = (( sender as StackPanel ).DataContext as MyObject).EventId_;

    string uri = String.Format("/Views/Event_View/Event_View.xaml?id={0}", eventid);
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative));
}
```

Then use the `NavigationContext` in paiden's answer to retrieve the value on the recieving page.

Comment: Hey thanks this looks as though it may work. I am testing it out now.